# Selecting half the elements with :nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Take the following code for instance:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello World</li>
  <li>Hello World</li>
  <li>Hello World</li>
  <li>Hello World</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible, using `:nth-child()` or otherwise, to select exactly **half** of the total elements? The code should select the first/last *two* `li`s in the above instance, then if I were to increase the number of `li`s to six, it would select the first/last *three*.

I feel I'm going to have to use JavaScript...

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to use JavaScript; CSS has no ability to determine how many elements there are or syntax to specify a quantity.

Comment: so, you're gonna select all? just got to know as well where the middle is?

Comment: @DavidThomas Check my answer for determining how many elements there are in CSS (link to Lea Verou's post) and specifying a quantity: `:(first/last)-(of-type/child)(aN+b)` allows this. Also `li+li+li+li` for selecting N elements except M first ones. What you can't do is **arithmetic** and counting a *really* undefined number of elements (though DOM is unlikely to have an undefined number of elements, in *most* cases)

Comment: https://codepen.io/joeyhoer/pen/LzdKQN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you'd be able to get **anywhere near** to that in pure CSS is to do a selector on either `nth-child(odd)` or `nth-child(even)`. If you want exactly the last half (and not either odd or even), then you'd have to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Using jQuery, you could get them using:

```js
var yourList = $("ul li");

yourList = yourList.slice(0, Math.floor(yourList.length/2));
```

Comment: Aha, as I feared. I was trying to figure out an equation, but it appears there is not one. Thanks for the JS snippet!

Comment: @FelipeAls LOL +1 for the effort, but that's still a static solution :).

Comment: Static? CSS is static, yes. Did you mean limited (to N elements)?

Answer (score 18):

You can select half of the elements in **pure CSS**... up to a point.
The only drawback is that you've to know the maximum number of total items. Could be 150 but it would then not work with 151.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tcK3F/ (*)

Minimal CSS:

```css
/* selecting half or more items. Up to 6 */
li:first-child:last-child,
li:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2),
li:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3),
li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+4),
li:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+5),
li:nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(-n+6) {
  color: white;
  background: darkblue;
}

/* selecting half or less items. Up to 6 */
li:nth-child(n+2):last-child,
li:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+2),
li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+3),
li:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+4),
li:nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(-n+5),
li:nth-child(n+7):nth-last-child(-n+6){
  font-style: italic;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Based on an idea from:
The trick is from André Luís and seen in a post from Lea Verou: [Styling elements based on sibling count](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/). I adapted it to your need of a split selection.

Quick explanation:
`:nth-last-child(-n+3)` will select the 3 *last* items from a parent; `:nth-child(n+3)` will select all items *except the first* 3 ones. Combine them and you can select elements in pure CSS based on what follow them (or how many children are in a parent). Except you'll have to combine 75 of them with 74 commas if you want this trick to work with 150 elements... :)

Compatibility is IE9+ (JS polyfills exist)

(*)
first part of HTML code: even number of list items;
second part: odd number of list items

first CSS rule: will select last N from 2N items or last N+1/2 items from 2N+1 and style them in white on blue (ex: 3 items in a total of 5 or 6).
second CSS rule: will select last N from 2N items or last N-1/2 items from 2N+1 and style them with red border and italic (ex: 2 items in a total of 4 or 5)

Comment: It's not nice, and I wouldn't recommend doing it, but just ... wow. That's some good out-of-the-box, horrible hacky workaround thinking right there :P

Comment: I refactor the code by mixins so that it doesn't have so many lines:). https://codepen.io/mingyena/pen/gOOZNrz

Answer (score 3):

### [Examples](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/72hxonuk/)

Create a CSS class with style for those elements:

```css
.half {
    background-color: #18D;
}
```

Then, use jQuery to add that class to the specified set of elements:

```js
$(function () {
  var $lis = $('ul li')
  var length = $lis.length

  // Add class to first half:
  $lis.slice(0, Math.floor(length / 2)).addClass('first')

  // Add class to last half:
  $lis.slice(length - Math.floor(length / 2)).addClass('first')
})
```

If you do want to **include** the element in the middle in the event of an odd amount of elements, change `Math.floor` to `Math.ceil`. All possibilities can be seen in the [examples](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/72hxonuk/).