# On textbox focus, how can you change the background color of the element prior to it with only CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I currently have a form with multiple fields set up like this (we're using Twitter Bootstrap):

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input id="contactEmail" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
</div>
```

What I want to do is when the textbox gets focus (`#contactEmail:focus`), change the background color of `span.add-on`. I'm familiar with CSS selectors to get the [next sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), but that would only work if the textbox immediately *preceded* `span.add-on`. Is there way to get the previous sibling using only CSS? We're aren't supporting IE7 or below, so anything that works for IE8+ would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's impossible to achieve this....use javascript/jquery

Comment: css wont work "the way up", sorry i think you need JavaScript for this one

Comment: Use jQuery or change order inside `.input-prepend` :)

Comment: ah well, a little javascript never hurt. Thanks for the prompt replies guys :)

Comment: Of course, you can change order and later use float-left on input, then change border-radius to get design like this, and that will work. But is much easier with little javascript :)

Comment: You lack a `label` close to your input (or at least a `title` attribute on it). It can be `.visually-hidden` (that is, off viewport but still read by screen readers and such) and as usual must be associated via the `for`/`id` attributes on resp. `label` and `input`. Relevant Technique: [Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html). The `placeholder` attribute is NOT a label, check HTML Living Standard or HTML5 documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to select a previous sibling using **only** CSS. It can however, be achieved simply by using Javascript/jQuery ([.previoussibling](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) respectively).

Comment: I was hoping to minimize javascript usage, but looks like I'll have to use it for this. Thanks for the prompt reply :D

Comment: Please see my comment to Tamil's answer. There are ways to select previous siblings under certain circumstances (but not here, OK ;) )

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to achieve previous sibling using css

Comment: It's possible with `nth-last-child()` or `nth-last-of-type()` combined with other selectors to [select previous siblings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15467744/137626) (see link to Lea Verou's post). Yes it's limited but not *impossible* in all cases.