# Change styling when add new sibling in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a container with children:

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Sometimes I want to add another child (server-side) into the container and change the styling of the other children to make room for their new sibling. It would become:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="special"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**Can I achieve this purely in CSS? Are there fancy new selectors (CSS4?) that I can use?**

I want to avoid JavaScript or changing the attributes (classes) of any of the elements. I did read about the lack of parent selectors in CSS but the articles I read are a couple of years old, so I suspect there might be some brand new selectors I can take advantage of.

Comment: Is there a known number of children at the beginning or can it be anything from 1 to 12? There's a trick for that case with `:nth-last-child()` / `:nth-child()` otherwise no parent or preceding sibling selector (idea was discussed at W3C CSS Working Group and cancelled; won't exist)

Comment: I considered using `:nth` but the number of children are unknown. :(

Comment: @FelipeAls Parent selectors were cancelled?

Comment: The question seems to postulate that CSS could know which element has been added even though it has not been indicated as added in any way. The problem becomes trivial (up to a point) if the added element has a `class` attribute, for example. But if you wish to “change the styling of the other children to make room for their new sibling” (presumably, due to poor design decisions in styling in general), then you can use sibling selectors (provided that the added element can be identified in HTML and CSS terms). It is very unclear what the real problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container #special {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
#container div {
  /* already float: none; by default */
  background: white;
}
```

is the simplest way to style elements differently in CSS: all div are styled because of the second rule (*whether or not the special element exists or not*) and the first rule will apply to one special element if it exists, with more specificity than the first one. Both rules will apply so properties in the first rule should override those in the second rule.

Now if you want to style the *other* divs differently when the special element exists:
In your example, no div precedes the special one so you don't need a preceding sibling selector; using the general sibling selector is sufficient:

```
#container div {
  padding: 5px;
}
#container #special ~ div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Could the special element be also created in 2nd, 3rd, etc position?
Then a similar trick to [selecting first half of the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466898/selecting-half-the-elements-with-nth-child/15467744#15467744) could be used (combination of `:nth-child()`/`:nth-last-child()`, but it has limitations, like an upper bound of elements to be set and it won't work with more elements than that - and the selector will be looooong and relatively inefficient. Will gzip really really well though :) )

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your sibling selector worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you could try some sibling selectors along with not selectors... something like:

```
.special+div:not(.special){ /*some special style here*/ }
.special+div+div:not(.special){ /*some special style here*/ }
.special+div+div+div:not(.special){ /*some special style here*/ }
```

up to n divs...

```
.special+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div+div:not(.special){ /*some special style here*/ }
```

if you have access to scss you can do something like:

```
@for $i from 1 through X { //REPLACE X WITH A NUMBER
 .special @for $j from 1 through $i {+div}:not(.special):{/*some special style here*/};
}
```

I'm just guessing about the scss formula, but it should be something like that :D

Also, depending on what you want to achieve there might be other options. Could you be more specific on the styles you want to apply?

Comment: (For some reason that may be a bad one) OP uses `#special`, not `.special`

Comment: You're trying to style the last written `div` of your selectors, right? How doess it style `.special`? And in your current case (that doesn't work imo), why not use `~` instead of `+`?

Comment: @Leo I never thought of doing this. Sure, it'd be a lot of code to select the expected number of siblings and it could potentially not select all of them, but it's a great attempt. I'll try it out.

Comment: For what I understand, you want to change the style of all the elements after the one added at the beginning. if you're going to add just one element with a certain ID you can skip the :not(.special) at the end, and replace the class selector with an id selector at the beginning, I made it into different lines because I think it could be easier to read, but you can allways do something like #special+div, #special+div+div, ...., #special+div+div+div...+div { /*style here*/ }.  If you use a class, it will give you the chance to add more div's styling only the originals.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This won't ever be supported by CSS. Even with advanced selectors in CSS4, they are **selectors**. They select something that is in the DOM. They can't produce a new HTML element.

To do this in jQuery, just use the [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method

```
$("div.special").before("#container div:first")
```

Comment: "*They can't produce a new HTML element.*": it'll (or won't) be generated server-side as stated by OP. And (for some reason that may be a bad one) OP uses `#special`, not `.special`

Comment: As I said in the OP, I generate the HTML server-side when the page is drawn. I'm seeking a selector, which I'm sure is in CSS4.

Comment: @FelipeAls I use `#special` as an example. The code is provided is not the actual code.

Comment: @CodyGuldner That'll style even when the special element is not there, causing the page to look out of whack.

Comment: No it won't. If you use `#container div:not(.special)`, it will target all `div`s in a `#container` that don't have a class of special

Comment: @CodyGuldner I know. My question is how to do this _sometimes_, because the special element won't always be there. Your code will apply the styling fine, but what happens when the special element does not exist?

Comment: @Jazza The styles will still apply, because the `div`s still don't have that class