# :nth-last-child to select second half of list of arbitrary length

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given an list of arbitrary length, how do I select the second half of the list items?

For a list where I know what the number of list items will be I can use `nth-last-child(-n+x)`, where `x` is the number of list items / 2, for example:

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+5) {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

But how do I do this where I do not know how many list items there will be? There will always be an even number of list items.

Comment: Don't think is possible with pure css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no way to cover all cases in CSS, you can cover as many as you're willing to code for.

```css
li:last-child,
li:nth-last-child(2):not(:first-child),
li:nth-last-child(3):not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
li:nth-last-child(4):not(:nth-child(-n+3)),
li:nth-last-child(5):not(:nth-child(-n+4))
/* ...... */
{
  color:red;
}
```

```css
li:last-child,
li:nth-last-child(2):not(:first-child),
li:nth-last-child(3):not(:nth-child(-n+2)),
li:nth-last-child(4):not(:nth-child(-n+3)),
li:nth-last-child(5):not(:nth-child(-n+4))
/* ...... */
{
  color:red;
}

ul{float:left}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>(not coded for)</li>
    <li>(this should be red)</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the css-only approach. However I am going to use JS and add a class.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in pure CSS, as already answered here: [Selecting half the elements with :nth-child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466898/selecting-half-the-elements-with-nth-child)

You will need to use JavaScript to select half the items you want, if you don't know how many items you will have.

Comment: If you've found a duplicate, you should vote to close as a duplicate (once you get close-vote powers). Otherwise, you're not contributing anything new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, thank you. Once I get the powers, I'll remeber this.