# Different backgrounds for only second half of child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How I can set different background colors for only second half of child elements? For example see the following picture:

[image: First half is back and second half is red]

And my HTML codes:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    ...
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't add class to child elements, so I must doing it only with CSS. I tried to use `:nth-child` but I did not succeed.

Comment: I recommend to you to make tests with this tool (or another that you want): https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: there's no pure css method to do what you want to do, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466898/selecting-half-the-elements-with-nth-child

Comment: It depends entirely on your layout, which means you'll need to show your CSS along with your markup. For one thing, it's very unlikely that all the red boxes are simply the first 15 elements - more likely, this is laid out using floats, in which case you're probably looking at elements 1 to 5, 11 to 15 and 21 to 25. There's also the total number of elements, whether the number of boxes in a row can vary... there are so many parameters that there's no way you could construct a generic selector that would cover all cases.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this with pure CSS is if you know the number of child `<div class="item">` elements there are. For example, if there are 100 elements, you can select the second 50 using the `nth-child()` selector with formula `an + b`. `b` is the index of the first child element you wish to select, `a` is the cycle size and `n` is a counter. Here, we choose `a = 1` and `b = 51`

```
div.items div.item:nth-child(n+51) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

If you don't know the number of child elements, then you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: It's a very difficult problem, only if the OP knows the number will achieve it. Upvote to you :)

Comment: it won't do what you want it to do. as he has it split vertically, you'd just be taking the second half, of the number of div. the correct way using this method, is to break it up further into rows and know how many belong on a single row. but there's no pure css way to do and the person has to modify the html

Comment: +Daemedeor I agree. In addition we also would need to know how the responsive state of these items look like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! I can found a solution:

```
.items .item:nth-child(10n+6) {background: red;}
.items .item:nth-child(10n+7) {background: red;}
.items .item:nth-child(10n+8) {background: red;}
.items .item:nth-child(10n+9) {background: red;}
.items .item:nth-child(10n+10) {background: red;}
```